# Convert object collection to dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following List of object collection.

```
column1:
Point data type
x=10,y=20
```

I have filtered that `Point` column using `linq ofType<Point>`.

```
Var XYLocations = Source.Select(g => g.ofType<Point>).ToList();
```

Now `XYLocations` contains duplicates.

From that list, I want to use linq to convert the list to `dictionary<Point,List<int>>` in which point is the key key and the corresponding matching row indixes act as values.

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar toggles indentation. For inline code, use backticks ("`"). Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```
var xyLocations = //initialization
var dictionary = xyLocations
                     .Select((p, i) => new Tuple<Point, int>(p, i))
                     .GroupBy(tp => tp.Item1, tp => tp.Item2)
                     .ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key, gr => gr.ToList());
```

If you don't have Tuple you can use anonymous type instead:

```
var dictionary = xyLocations
                     .Select((p, i) => new {Item1 = p, Item2 = i})
                     .GroupBy(tp => tp.Item1, tp => tp.Item2)
                     .ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key, gr => gr.ToList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am not using .Net 4.0. Using only 3.5
Hence tuple is not available. Could you please suggest other way? Thanks

Comment: Thanks MAKKAM. Its working but not the way I want. Result of the xylocations is: [0] -> [0] -> {X =10, Y=20}; [1] -> [1] -> {X=10;Y-20};etc..Result of dictionary is: [0] -> Key ->{X =10, Y=20} & Value [0] -> 0; [1] -> Key -> {X=10, Y =20} & Value[0] ->1. It is not grouping same Point with many row index.

Comment: @Suresh, I've put xyLocation line just for example. I have no idea how do you get it. I propose that xyLocation is valid List<Point> object. You have to check just a dictionary initialization.

Comment: @Suresh, what's the Point actually? Make sure that this class implements IEqualityComparer interface. Otherwise GroupBy won't have any idea how to compare and group your points. Another option is to create your own comparer and pass it to the method. Check GroupBy on MSDN.

Comment: I am just beginner to C#. I dont know how to I convey my problem. I will go with traditional looping to group it.for (int i = 0; i < totalpts; )
{
 Point d = xyLocations[i].Single();
                        List<int> groupZ = new List<int>();
                        int ns = xyLocations.Count(n => n.Single() == d);
                        for (int count = i; count < i + ns; count++)
                        {
                            groupZ.Add(count);
                        }
                        setofvalues.Add(d, groupZ);
                        i += ns;
                    }

Comment: @Suresh, the code above works for me. If it doesn't work for you, then you should consider to create SSCCE (check http://sscce.org/) Include just Point class implementation, list initialization with constants, dictionary initialization, expected and actual results. Now, it's almost impossible to understand what's the problem.